# Python variable working outside of function, but not inside

Tags: python, arcpy

I have an issue where I am trying to copy feature classes into a geodatabase.  I am looping through all the feature classes in the folder and copying only the polygon feature classes.  My problem is, that when I copy the first polygon feature class it renames it 'shp', and then tries to name the second 'shp' as well.  The variable `fcname` returns the full feature class names ('counties.shp' and 'new_mexico.shp') outside of the copy function, but it does not work properly inside the function.

The code below has the function that I want to run commented out to test the `fcname` variable. There are five feature classes in the folder with two of them being polygon feature classes.  When uncommented the code runs all the way through the first polygon feature class where `fcname` results in 'shp' instead of 'counties.shp'.  It does the same for the second feature class which results in an error since 'shp' already exists in the `gdb`.

```
import arcpy

# Set initial variables with different pathnames available 
# whether I am working on my home or work computer

pathhome = "G:/ESRIScriptArcGIS/Python/Data/Exercise06"
pathwork = "C:/ESRIPress/Python/Data/Exercise06"
arcpy.env.workspace = pathwork
gdbname ="NewDatabase.gdb"

fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

# Create new gdb
##arcpy.management.CreateFileGDB(path, gdbname)
newgdb = path + "/" + gdbname

# Loop through list
for fc in fclist:
    desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
    fcname = desc.name
    outpath = newgdb + "/" + fcname

    # Check for polygon then copy
    if desc.shapeType == "Polygon":
        ##arcpy.management.CopyFeatures(fcname,outpath)
        ##print fcname + "copied."
        print fcname
    else:
        print "Not a polygon feature class"
```

Thank you to anyone who can help!

Comment: Just to make sure I've understood - `fcname` is perfectly file in the code you've posted, but once it goes into `CopyFeatures` it gets truncated? Or something else?

Comment: It was getting truncated down to just shp.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to the problem.  `CopyFeatures` does not want a full file path in the `out_feature_class` argument.  I stripped the ".shp" from the end of the file path and it worked.

I also took Hector's advice and filtered down to just the polygons in the `ListFeatureClasses` arguments, however, I still needed the loop to walk through the resulting list and copy each feature class.

Here is the resulting code that worked.

```
import arcpy

# Set initial variables with different pathnames available
# whether I am working on my home or work computer

pathhome = "G:/ESRIScriptArcGIS/Python/Data/Exercise06"
pathwork = "C:/ESRIPress/Python/Data/Exercise06"
arcpy.env.workspace = pathwork
gdbname ="NewDatabase.gdb"

fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("", "Polygon")

# Create new gdb
arcpy.management.CreateFileGDB(pathwork, gdbname)
newgdb = pathwork + "/" + gdbname

# Loop through list
for fc in fclist:
    desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
    fcname = str(desc.name)
    outpath = newgdb + "/" + fcname.replace(".shp","")



    arcpy.management.CopyFeatures(fcname,outpath)
    print fcname + " has been copied."
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have an error in your code. However, I see more evident the error in your approach.

If your goal is to filter the classes by shape, you could use the argument `feature_type` accepted by the `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()` function.

See the documentation: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/listfeatureclasses.htm

You won't need to use the for loop any more to filter your data.